# I'm trying to add these variables into a string paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relativity new to java script and I am working on a project in class which requires us to take inputs, change them to variables and implement them within a paragraph. We learnt about this thing called  template literals which I attempted but it has not worked. I was wondering if there is something I have missed or another way to do this.

```
<button onclick="myFunction">Create my story!</button>
<script> 
    let name = document.getElementById("name") 
    let classAt = document.getElementById("class") 
    let prof = document.getElementById("prof") 
    let adject = document.getElementById("Adject") 
    let place = document.getElementById("place") 
    let length = document.getElementById("time") 
    let thing = document.getElementById("thing") 
    let person = document.getElementById("person") 
    let family = document.getElementById("fam") 

    function myFunction() {
        window.alert("Please Excuse ${name} from ${class} today.His 
        ${prof} says he is too ${Adject} to attend the ${place}. He 
        will return to school in ${time}. Please send their ${thing} 
        home with ${person}, his sister. signed, ${name}'s ${fam}") 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: template literals use `\`` not `"`

Comment: You're also not invoking the function properly, nor are you getting the text from the elements there.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text with the character `` ` `` to create a template literal in Javascript. Then invoke the function.

```
function myFunction() {
    window.alert(`Please Excuse ${name} from ${class} today.His 
    ${prof} says he is too ${Adject} to attend the ${place}. He 
    will return to school in ${time}. Please send their ${thing} 
    home with ${person}, his sister. signed, ${name}'s ${fam}`) 
}

myFunction();
```

To get the text content from an HTML element, you can try something like:

```
const name = document.getElementById("name").textContent;
```

Use `const` instead of `let`if you are not intending to alter the value of the variable.

Hope that solves your problem.